# Changing state according to previous state in redux

Tags: redux

I am developing a React-Redux app.
I have a requirement where I need to change state according to the values in the previous state.

I tried passing the previous state using this.props to my action but what I receive in my action is not the expected value. 
So is it a fine approach to pass the previous state using this.props to the action and take comparison decisions in the reducer or should look out for some other comparison logic ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you should be using lifecycle methods, specifically `ComponentWillReceiveProps`. Read more about it and others here: http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

you can use:

```
ComponentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(this.props.yourProp === desiredValue) doSomething; 
}
```

Also, you can compare `this.props.yourPropName` (which is the current state of props) and `nextProps.yourPropName` which is the upcoming prop state. Redux here is irrelevant, as this is normal way of mutating according to the incoming props, weather from Redux or standard parent component.